How to use OpenAI Assistants with Openrouter
I recently came across a platform called apiepie.ai that offers GPT-4 access through something called openrouter. I would like to know if someone has used assistants with this option like with this code, because in the documentation there's only the basic send message code :
async function createThread() {
    try {
        const thread = await openai.beta.threads.create();
        return thread.id;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al crear el hilo:", error);
        return null;
    }
}

async function sendMessageToOpenAI(threadId, message) {
    try {
        const response = await openai.beta.threads.messages.create(threadId, {
            role: "user",
            content: message
        });
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al enviar mensaje a OpenAI:", error);
        return null;
    }
}

async function getResponseFromOpenAI(threadId, assistantId) {
    try {
        const run = await openai.beta.threads.runs.create(threadId, {
            assistant_id: assistantId.id,
        });
        // console.log(`run : ${run}`)
        
        let runResponse = await openai.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(threadId, run.id);
        console.log(`runresponse : ${runResponse}`)
        
        while (runResponse.status !== "completed") {
            // Pausar brevemente para evitar hacer solicitudes continuas en un bucle rápido
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Espera 1 segundo
            runResponse = await openai.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(threadId, run.id);
            console.log(`runresponse 2  threadid: ${runResponse}`)
            console.log(runResponse.thread_id)
            
        }

        return runResponse;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener respuesta de OpenAI:", error);
        return null;
    }
}


